# JPA Buddy, JPA Entity from POJO ignoring parent definition

Tags: jpa-buddy

I use the JPA Buddy (2023.3.5-232) plugin in the Intellij IDEA editor (Ultimate Edition 2023.2.3). My project is a SpringBoot application, and my database is a postgresql database.

JPA Entity from POJO is ignoring parent definition.

I tried to specify as parent a @MappedSuperClass annotated class

Answer (score 0):

If you mean JPA Buddy doesn't see any attributes in a parent DTO - it's a bug, I created a ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JPAB-2680/JPA-Entity-from-POJO-doesnt-see-parent-DTO-attributes

Comment: In the specific case i tried to define a parent entity (an existing one): as mentioned i tried to use as parent @MappedSuperClass annotated entity and also a @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) annotated entity with no luck; i was expecting to see inherited attriubutes in wizard

Comment: You see attributes that would be created. Why do you need to see attributes in the parent entity? What do you expect to make with them in the wizard?